# Http Websocket as Akka Stream Source

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'd like to listen on a websocket using akka streams. That is, I'd like to treat it as nothing but a `Source`.

However, all [official examples](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html) treat the websocket connection as a `Flow`.

My current approach is using the `websocketClientFlow` in combination with a `Source.maybe`. This eventually results in the upstream failing due to a `TcpIdleTimeoutException`, when there are no new `Message`s being sent down the stream.

Therefore, my question is twofold:

1. Is there a way – which I obviously missed – to treat a websocket as just a `Source`?
2. If using the `Flow` is the only option, how does one handle the `TcpIdleTimeoutException` properly? The exception can not be handled by providing a stream supervision strategy. Restarting the source by using a `RestartSource` doesn't help either, because the source is not the problem.

## Update

So I tried two different approaches, setting the idle timeout to 1 second for convenience

*application.conf*

```
akka.http.client.idle-timeout = 1s
```

#### Using keepAlive (as suggested by Stefano)

```
Source.<Message>maybe()
    .keepAlive(Duration.apply(1, "second"), () -> (Message) TextMessage.create("keepalive"))
    .viaMat(Http.get(system).webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest.create(websocketUri)), Keep.right())
    { ... }
```

When doing this, the Upstream still fails with a `TcpIdleTimeoutException`.

#### Using RestartFlow

However, I found out about [this approach](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.8/stream/stream-error.html?language=java#delayed-restarts-with-a-backoff-stage), using a `RestartFlow`:

```
final Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> restartWebsocketFlow = RestartFlow.withBackoff(
    Duration.apply(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    Duration.apply(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    0.2,
    () -> createWebsocketFlow(system, websocketUri)
);

Source.<Message>maybe()
    .viaMat(restartWebsocketFlow, Keep.right()) // One can treat this part of the resulting graph as a `Source<Message, NotUsed>`
    { ... }

(...)

private Flow<Message, Message, CompletionStage<WebSocketUpgradeResponse>> createWebsocketFlow(final ActorSystem system, final String websocketUri) {
    return Http.get(system).webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest.create(websocketUri));
}
```

This works in that I can treat the websocket as a Source (although artifically, as explained by Stefano) and keep the tcp connection alive by restarting the `websocketClientFlow` whenever an `Exception` occurs.

This doesn't feel like the optimal solution though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No. WebSocket is a bidirectional channel, and Akka-HTTP therefore models it as a `Flow`. If in your specific case you care only about one side of the channel, it's up to you to form a `Flow` with a "muted" side, by using either `Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, mySource)` or `Flow.fromSinkAndSource(mySink, Source.maybe)`, depending on the case.
2. as per the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.8/scala/http/websocket-support.html#example):

   > Inactive WebSocket connections will be dropped according to the
   >   idle-timeout settings. In case you need to keep inactive connections
   >   alive, you can either tweak your idle-timeout or inject ‘keep-alive’
   >   messages regularly.

   There is an ad-hoc combinator to inject keep-alive messages, see the example below and this [Akka cookbook recipe](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html?language=scala#injecting-keep-alive-messages-into-a-stream-of-bytestrings). NB: this should happen on the client side.

   `src.keepAlive(1.second, () => TextMessage.Strict("ping"))`

Comment: Your answer to #1 makes perfect sense. I did pretty much what u suggested, but without understanding websockets properly. On #2: I came up with using a `RestartFlow` to reset the websocket connection in case of an exception. I tried keepalives before that, but the messages were just sent downstream... Which didn't do any good. So how does this work then? Does one have to send keepalives from the source *through* the websocket flow?

Comment: As in e.g.: `Source[Message].maybe.keepAlive(...).viaMat(websocketClientFlow)...`? (will post an example asap if that helps)

Comment: sorry if I didn't clarify before, the `keepAlive` injection should happen on the client side. The clients should be responsible for keeping their connection alive, whilst the server should employ idle-timeouts to avoid connection thrashing in case clients disappear. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. Are you looking for [`asSourceOf`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html#consuming-json-streaming-uploads)?

```
path("measurements") {
  entity(asSourceOf[Measurement]) { measurements =>
    // measurement has type Source[Measurement, NotUsed]
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope. I was looking for a "listen-only" websocket `Source`, client side.